# How can I add a link to the SharePoint "create" page?

Tags: sharepoint, custom-lists

I have a custom feature, and I'd like to link to that functionality from a link on the "Create" page -- the create.aspx page that you get to from the Site Actions menu.  I'd be happy to do this either declaratively within my feature's element manifest or programmatically in some feature activation code, but I have no idea if it's possible or how to begin.  In the meantime, I have a link in the Site Actions menu, but I'd like to move it to a more logically appropriate location in the Create page.

In the end, I'd like to have a link at the bottom of the "Custom Lists" column on the Create page that says "Chris's Custom List", and that link would point to my custom application page to initiate this custom list creation process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to blame my rather high fever at the time, because my answer is just plain wrong.

You can add custom links to the custom lists column if you just add a list template that asets the NewPage property of the ListTemplate element.

I have no idea why I answered what I did, but to make up for any confusion I have written an article that demonstrates [custom SharePoint list creation](http://furuknap.blogspot.com/2009/01/consuming-rss-or-atom-feed-in.html) as well as a variety of other features.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly you have no supportable option to add custom links to the Custom Lists column. The column is generated from the installed list templates, and you only method for adding anything to that column is adding a list template, which does not give you control over which link will be generated.

On the Create page you can add your own custom links only to the Web Pages column. To do so, add a CustomAction with Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.Create" and a GroupId="WebPages":

```
    <CustomAction
 Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.Create"
 GroupId="WebPages"
 Title="Chris's Custom List">
      <UrlAction Url="custompage.aspx"/>
    </CustomAction>
```

You may, of course, modify the create.aspx file if you do not care about supportability or plan to ever upgrade SharePoint again.

.b